# Angular 5 select options from function

Tags: angular, angular5, chained-select

I'm trying to figure out how to do chained selects with Angular 5.  This is what I have so far.  The first `select` works, the second one is not.

```html
<select [ngModel]="selectedTag" (change)="tagChanged()" [disabled]="!element.checked">
  <option *ngFor="let tag of tags">
    {{tag}}
  </option>
</select>

<select multiple="multiple" class="stations">
    <option *ngFor="let station of stationsByTag()">
        {{station}}
    </option>
</select>
```

I think the `stationsByTag()` is only being called once.

Comment: stationsByTag is called once because that function is expected to return the array you are iterating on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what stationsByTag() looks like but you likely need to set a currentTag on the component when it's selected and update stationsByTag based on that.

Comment: OK, changing `stationsByTag` to just be a variable and not a function made this work.  Thanks.